# Is logical to use React useCallback for this example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React hooks, in one of parts in our projects, we have a function to handle modal display in cards:

```js
const toggleModal = () => setModalDisplay(!modalDisplay)
```

in this case, I have to pass this function to each child components... maybe for 10 or 1000 children!

So, regard to React JS DOC `useCallback` returns a memoized function to reduce the memory usage and handle expensive computing. but I have to pass params to second argument to refresh callback and return the new one.

but in this case, we have a state to handle modal toggle, that every times has changes between true and false. so, with considering the logic of `useCallback` and our use case, if I use `useCallback` for this example, practically that function (`toggleModal`) updates every times and `useCallback` is useless for this use case.

for example:

```js
const memoizedModalToggle = useCallback(
  () => {
    setModalDisplay(!modalDisplay)
  },
  [modalDisplay],
);
```

finally, is this a correct using of `useCallback`? or I have mistake in implementation and logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused between set the states and update callback functions in a memoized function with `useCallback`

For example, you can memoized your callback function with an empty array of dependencies:

```js
const memoizedModalToggle = useCallback(
  () => {
    setModalDisplay(!modalDisplay)
  },
  []
);
```

it will be something like `useEffect` logic for callback functions.

Also you can use `Set()` object to test this flow, because `Set` is able to store unique functions by references and you are able to use `set.size()` for checking the number of callbacks have generated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, use useCallback when you want to avoid having to update a component or function when the state changes

example:

```
    {useCallback(<TableStore
        params={[JSON.stringify([selectedRoute]), data]} 
        tableName="custom_table" 
        method="Select"
    >
        <ReactTable
            allowExport
            onRowClick={onRowClick}
            columns={columns}
            allowSelection={false}
        />
    </TableStore>, [selectedRoute, data])}
```

Here the table will change and update only when we click on the row or when our data has been updated.

in your case, not need to use useCallback

Comment: you wrapped a component with `useCallback` to reduce re-renders? I think it was better to use `React.memo()` instead?

Comment: it component in render case